# Changing formatted address state code to state name in Woocommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Instead of 2 letter state abbreviation, I would like to show the full state name.

On this page /plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php

```
<div class="order_data_column">
                    <h3>
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Billing', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <a href="#" class="edit_address"><?php esc_html_e( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#" class="load_customer_billing" style="display:none;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Load billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="address">
                        <?php

                        // Display values.
                        if ( $order->get_formatted_billing_address() ) {
                            echo '<p>' . wp_kses( $order->get_formatted_billing_address(), array( 'br' => array() ) ) . '</p>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<p class="none_set"><strong>' . __( 'Address:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'No billing address set.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                        }

                        foreach ( self::$billing_fields as $key => $field ) {
                            if ( isset( $field['show'] ) && false === $field['show'] ) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            $field_name = 'billing_' . $key;

                            if ( isset( $field['value'] ) ) {
                                $field_value = $field['value'];
                            } elseif ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
                                $field_value = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
                            } else {
                                $field_value = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
                            }

                            if ( 'billing_phone' === $field_name ) {
                                $field_value = wc_make_phone_clickable( $field_value );
                            } else {
                                $field_value = make_clickable( esc_html( $field_value ) );
                            }

                            if ( $field_value ) {
                                echo '<p><strong>' . esc_html( $field['label'] ) . ':</strong> ' . wp_kses_post( $field_value ) . '</p>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
</div>
```

[image: Abbreviation -> Full state name?]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only country in Woocommerce, that display the state as a code in the formatted address is USA.

To display the state name for USA in the formatted billing or shipping addresses, use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'change_localisation_usa_state_format', 20, 2 );
function change_localisation_usa_state_format( $address_formats ){
    $address_formats['US'] = "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}, {state} {postcode}\n{country}";

    return $address_formats;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer, however, thanks to WooCommerce App, it still is abbreviated there.  I am guessing we don't have control over the data the app is pulling and the data itself needs to be modified?

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3603364/a41b20339e2a600dcca7fe8c6e618368

Comment: @centurypixel This answer doesn't handle **WooCommerce App** *(I really don't know that much about)* and your question was related to backend… On a classic web site through a browser, the frontend displays correctly the state name for USA states on the formatted address.